# how to run codeception acceptance testing with selenium on remote server

Tags: java, php, linux, selenium, codeception

I have a testing server for my phpunit, and now we want to add our codeception acceptance testing with selenium.

But as you the remote server has no "desktop" so it will not open a browser like in our developers computers.

I tried installing firefox on the machine but I still get this error:

```
Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: LINUX      
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'                  
System info: host: 'testdev', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:   
'3.2.0-23-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_65'                                                     
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

so now I did this

```
  WebDriver:
         url: 'http://example.com/'
         browser: firefox
         capabilities:
              binary: "/usr/bin/firefox"
```

and I get this error:

```
Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:  
  Error: no display specified                                                               
  Error: no display specified
```

is it possible what I'm doing?

or I must have a "screen"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use Selenium with Firefox, or Chrome, etc - you need a linux distro that has a User Interface.

If you are on a linux machine that doesn't have a display (aka, just a terminal), then you can research Selenium HTMLUnit (headless browsing).

Answer (score 0):

You could do headless browsing via the PHPBrowser, or you could install a GUI like xfce4 vnc4server, which will give you a virtual desktop to run Firefox in. This has the added bonus that you can watch the test run graphically.